Android app Widget list view item button click not working on Android 14
I have a listview inside the widget. Data is set from api response. In list there are 2 buttons, on click of buttons i need data in Widget Provider class. Below is the code in provider class.
val clickIntent = Intent(context, WidgetProvider::class.java).apply {
            action = CLICK_ACTION
        }

        clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
        clickIntent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)))

        val clickPendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        } else {
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
        }

        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listview, clickPendingIntent)

Above code is called inside onUpdate method.
Below code is for list item button click :
val fillInIntent = Intent()
                fillInIntent.setPackage(context.packageName)
                fillInIntent.setAction(CLICK_ACTION)
                val infos = Bundle()
                infos.putString("number", "1234")
                fillInIntent.putExtra("data", Gson().toJson(adapterItems[position]))
                fillInIntent.putExtras(infos)
                views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.ivCall, fillInIntent)

Below code is for getting data inside onReceive of Provider class
val lead_data = intent.getStringExtra("data")
val bundle = intent.extras

Here bundle is null. It is working fine on all the android versions except Android 14. Event is received but data is null.
Below is manifest code
<receiver
        android:name=".widget.WidgetProvider" 
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
          
            <action android:name="com.justdial.search.item_button_click_action" />
           

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/leads_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>

